# Need to check whether its the first date of the month or not in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
Student Name    Start Date  
ABC             2021-01-01  
DEF             2021-01-02  
GHI             2021-02-03  
JKL             2021-02-01  
MNO             2021-01-05  
PQR             2021-03-06  
STU             2021-03-01
```

Output

```
Student Name    Start Date  Month_Start
ABC             2021-01-01  TRUE
DEF             2021-01-02  FALSE
GHI             2021-02-03  FALSE
JKL             2021-02-01  TRUE
MNO             2021-01-05  FALSE
PQR             2021-03-06  FALSE
STU             2021-03-01  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `date_trunc()` you can achieve this:

```
select student_name, 
       start_date, 
       start_date = date_trunc('month', start_date)::date as month_start
from the_table
```

The cast `::date` is necessary, because `date_trunc()` returns a `timestamp` but we want to compare `date` values.